# Mensajes de Error al crear DB sqlite desde flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

estoy creando una base de datos SQLite desde flutter, por primera vez. El tema es que por más que busco no encuentro información sobre cómo ver mensajes de error que me retornan las llamadas de SQFLite y no me está creando la base de datos (al menos eso me parece). Mi código es el siguiente:

```
       class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;
  Future<Database> get db async {
    print("_db: $_db");
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, 'teknopartner.db');
    print('DB path ' + path);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);


    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    print('OnCreate');
    await db
        .execute('CREATE TABLE area (area_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descr TEXT, piso TEXT, beacon INTEGER, estado INTEGER)');
    print('creado' + db.path);


  }

  Future <Area> addArea(Area areaAdd) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    areaAdd.areaid = (await dbClient.insert('area', areaAdd.toMap())) as String;
    return areaAdd;
  }

  Future <Area> getArea(int beacon) async {
    var dbClient = await db;

    print('getre becon ' + beacon.toString());
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query("area",
        columns: ["area_id", "descr", "piso", "beacon", "estado"],
        where: 'beacon = ?',
        whereArgs: [beacon]);
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      print('bien');
      globals.miArea = Area.fromMap(maps.first);
      return Area.fromMap(maps.first);
    }
    print('mal error' );
    return null;
  }


  Future <int> deleteAreas() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete(
      'area',
    );
  }


  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

El dbhelper es llamado desde una función que uso para verificar el usurio en el servidor, y que me retorna tambien la información que voy a cargar en esta tabla. La función que l llama es esta:

```
refreshAreaList(List listAreas) {

  List<Area> _lArea = List<Area>();

  globals.dbHelper = DBHelper();

  globals.dbHelper.deleteAreas();

  _lArea =  listAreas
      .map((area) => new Area.fromJson(area))
      .toList();
  _lArea.forEach((n) =>
      globals.dbHelper.addArea(n));
}

Future<String> g_login(String usr, String pass, String camino) async {

  try{

  final response = await http.post(camino + '/Servicios/login_serv.php', body: {
    "usuario": usr,
    "clave": pass,
  });


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var datausuario = json.decode(response.body);
    print(datausuario);
    if (datausuario['nombre'] == '-1') {
      return '-1';
    } else {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString('Usuario', usr);
      prefs.setString('Cifrada', pass);
      prefs.setString('Camino', camino);
      globals.camino = camino;
      globals.Usuario = usr;
      globals.Nombre = datausuario['nombre'];
      globals.Pendientes = datausuario['cPendientes'].toString();
      globals.cAsignadas = datausuario['cAsignados'].toString();
      globals.cNoAsignadas = datausuario['cNoAsignados'].toString();
      globals.refrescar = int.parse(datausuario['refrescar_app']);
      globals.minAccuracy = double.parse(datausuario['minAccuracy']);
      globals.MaxBeaconRetry = int.parse(datausuario['time']);

      //aquí debo conectar la db y actualizarla, primero la borro y luego la lleno
      //List area = json.decode(datausuario['listareas']);
      //print("areas que llegan");
       //print(datausuario["listareas"]["records"]);
      refreshAreaList(datausuario["listareas"]["records"]);

      return globals.Nombre;
    }
  }else
    return '-2';} catch(e) {
    print("Error de coneccion !");
    return '-2';
  }
}
```

Me muestra el mensaje de DB path cada vez que trato de insertar una fila, y nunca me muestra el mensaje OnCreate, por lo que creo que no se está creando la base de datos y por eso trata de crearla cada vez que llamo al dbHelper.

esto es lo que sale en la consola cuando lo ejecuto desde el debug, estoy usando un celular Samsung para las pruebas:

> I/flutter ( 8840): {nombre: Maria del Pilar Fernandez, time: 10,
>   cPendientes: 43, cAsignados: 0, cNoAsignados: 0, refrescar_app: 5,
>   minAccuracy: 7, listareas: {records: [{area_id: 54, descr: Gerencia
>   General, piso: PISO16, beacon: 1601, estado: 0}, {area_id: 53, descr:
>   SubGerencias, piso: PISO15, beacon: 1501, estado: 0}, {area_id: 60,
>   descr: Baño Publico, piso: PISO14, beacon: 37, estado: 0}, {area_id:
>   51, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO13, beacon: 36, estado: 0},
>   {area_id: 50, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO12, beacon: 35, estado:
>   0}, {area_id: 49, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO11, beacon: 10,
>   estado: 0}, {area_id: 48, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO10, beacon:
>   9, estado: 0}, {area_id: 47, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO 9,
>   beacon: 8, estado: 0}, {area_id: 46, descr: Oncología, piso: PISO 9,
>   beacon: 16, estado: 0}, {area_id: 44, descr: Baño Público, piso: PISO
>   8, beacon: 7, estado: 0}, {area_id: 45, descr: Pediatría, piso: PISO
>   8, beacon: 999, estado: 0}, {area_id: 43, descr: Baño Público, piso:
>   PISO 7, bea I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter (
>   8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db:
>   null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null I/flutter ( 8840): _db: null
>   I/BeaconManager( 8840): BeaconManager started up on pid 8840 named
>   'cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean' for application package
>   'cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean'.  isMainProcess=true D/BeaconParser(
>   8840): Parsing beacon layout:
>   m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25 I/CycledLeScanner(
>   8840): This is Android 5.0.  We are using new scanning APIs
>   I/BeaconService( 8840): beaconService version 2.16.3 is starting up on
>   the main process W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator( 8840): Cannot find
>   match for this device.  Using default
>   W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator( 8840): Cannot find match for this
>   device.  Using default I/BeaconService( 8840): binding I/flutter (
>   8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db
>   I/flutter ( 8840): DB path
>   /data/data/cl.teknopartner.TeknoClean/app_flutter/teknopartner.db

Por favor, si tienen algún enlace que me ayude a ver cómo hacer seguimiento de los errores se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: prueba desinstalando e instalando nuevamente la app

Comment: nada, igual falla

Comment: agrega más información a tu pregunta, desde que método/clases invocas a la base de datos, que hay en el método `_onCreate` ,  en que dispositivo o simulador lo estás probando,  agrega el mensaje de error también (Desinstala el app) , luego flutter clean y prueba.

Comment: hola, gracias por tus consejos. Hise lo que me indicaste y luego de probar edité la consulta. Estoy planeando hacer pruebas en un pequeño programa de test para no complicarme con el código de mi app, que ya está bastante avanzada, si vez algo o tienes algún consejo más te lo agradeceré mucho

Comment: agrega el método deleteAreas y addArea , tambien agrega un print al inicio de este metodo : Future<Database> get db async {  y pinta  print("_db: $_db");

Comment: ya esos métodos existían, actualicé la consulta par poner el módulo completo, tambien agregé el print que me indicas, lo probé y actualicé el resultado en la consulta. Voy a analizarlo a ver si me da alguna idea, pero en principio solo confirmo que no se ha creado nada :(

Comment: entonces, no se imprime esto ? _db: $_db   en tu log ?

Comment: pon un try catch cuando abras la db : openDatabase ,  y llama a esto   globals.dbHelper = DBHelper(); globals.dbHelper.db;   en el main.dart , para que solo se cree la instancia al inicio de tu app, no lo vuelvas a llamar luego porque te va a crear una instancia nueva y va a terminar abriendo la bsae de datos muchas veces

Comment: se imprime _db:null, parece que actulicé mal la salida